# Basement ceiling/wall construction

Tags: basement-refinishing

I'm finishing my basement and need to use 2x2 furring strips to clear some plumbing and gas line runs. Should I install the furring strips first and build the walls up to the furring strips or walls first? Basically do you need a top plate to secure your dry wall or are the studs in the wall good enough support? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The furring strips go up first. You will need a top plate and a bottom plate to secure the drywall. You might find you need 2x4's depending on the thickness of your plumbing and gas lines. Don't forget the nail stop plates to protect the plumbing/electric lines.